# Passing Data from App delegate to View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I need to Pass an string from App delegate to my Initial View Controller , 
Can somebody listed me the best way to do it , also i tried to Save and Retrieve using NS user Defaults, but i doesn't work out properly .

Comment: It's not for some reason. The reason is quite explicit in that the purpose of the app's delegate is to respond to changes in the app's state. Using it as a dumping ground for data and constants is poor form and leads to a dependency on an object that isn't a contributing citizen in the MVC paradigm.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Interface:**

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject  {
  NSString *myString;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
...
@end
```

and in the .m file for the App Delegate you would write:

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate
@synthesize myString;
    myString = some string;
@end
```

Then, in viewcontroller.m file you can fetch:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
someString = appDelegate.myString;  //..to read
appDelegate.myString = some NSString;     //..to write
```

Comment: Your answer should contain written in capital letters: "My method is dangerous and bad practice, because it breaks encapsulation and creates global state."

Answer (score 20):

Here it is for Swift:

**View  Controller**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

Furthermore, if you have an object that you want to pass between view controllers (for example, I had CloudKit data I wanted to share) add this to the **App Delegate**:

```
    /* Function for any view controller to grab the instantiated CloudDataObject */
func getCloudData() ->CloudData{
    return cloudDataObject
}
```

Then back in the **View Controller**

```
var model : CloudData = self.appDelegate.getCloudData()
```

Answer (score 14):

You can access your root view controller like this from the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyViewController* mainController = (MyViewController*)  self.window.rootViewController;
    [mainController passData:@"hello"];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: passData from where? How is declared?

Answer (score 3):

*Using Swift 4.2:*

**Passing Data from AppDelegate to ViewController:**

```
let yourViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as? YourViewController
yourViewController?.passData(YOUR_DATA) // pass data
let data = yourViewController?.getData() // access data
```

**Passing Data from ViewController to AppDelegate:**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.passData(YOUR_DATA) // pass data
let data = appDelegate.getData() // access data
```

**Add below code to YourViewController or AppDelegate:**

```
private var data : String? // String? or any type you want
func getData() -> String? {
    return data
}
func passData(_ data : String?) {
    self.data = data
}
```