# Where to initialize PCL instanced in a Xamarin.iOS app?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin application, which I will at first have working on iOS, but plan to later expand to Android and other mobile platforms.

As such, I'm trying to keep as much common code in PCLs as possible.

My question: what is the best practise - in Xamarin.iOS for now - to initialize any dependent PCL code?

For now I have it in the `RootViewController` inside `ViewDidLoad()`

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    _engine = new MyEngine();
    View = new MainView(_engine);
}
```

Is this the right spot? I'd considered putting it in the ctor for the `RootViewController`, but there's a fair bit going on in the initialization code, which thus ran against "don't put heavy duty init code into a constructor".

Things that happen are:

- Load app settings
- If app is run for first time ever, load basic defaults
- Initialise other PCL libraries, such as a TextToSpeech module, a state engine (hence the name of the class above), etc
- Prepare a data grid based on XML or JSON input

Alternately, I though it should possibly go into the `AppDelegate` section, but that didn't sound right.

I'm still fairly new to mobile app dev in general and Xamarin in specific, though I've done C# native code for Windows for years. I just want to make sure I follow best practises, but there doesn't seem to be a "thou shalt" in this case.

Edit: I've extracted the solution based on @wishmaster's suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS the Appdelegate method is the best place for initialization code. The appdelegate also provides multiple delegate methods to give you feedback on application lifecyle events such as the method "[DidFinishLauchingWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)" 
. if you have a lot of data to download or long running tasks that your app depends on I would suggest you take a look [backgrounding for iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/ios_backgrounding_with_tasks/). 
A technique I have also used is for my first viewcontroller on IOS (or activity on Android) to display a splash screen and a loading indicator while i run some code to refresh the cache.

Comment: Excellent. I can see that I'll have to dive more into at least the basics of reading Swift and Obj-C. Coming from C# I'd naively  hoped I can stick to the little island of Xamarin documentation. Not so. The doc you linked explains some of the finer points of app launching, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In Xamarin the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() method is FinishedLaunching() - and the docs aren't by far as in-depth.

Comment: you got me on the right track and it works like a charm! I'll edit my question and put the solution into a separate answer, but you're still getting the Accepted answer credit!

Answer (score 0):

Using @wishmaster's pointers, this solution works like a charm:

In `AppDelegate.cs`

```
// in the global section put any data you may make available elsewhere
private var _engine;
public Engine => _engine;

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    /*
     * Do whatever init needs to happen here, if you need to make this
     * available elsewhere, ensure you have properties or accessors,
     * as above.
     */
    _engine = new MyEngine();
    return true;
}
```

Then in `RootViewController.cs` using a similar approach to these examples in [Obc-C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15050028/4053717) or [Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28438387/4053717) you can access the information through a property pointing at the AppDelegate.

```
var myappdelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;
var engine = myappdelegate.Engine;
View = new MainView(engine);
```

The result resulted in a snappier start up of the application, because the initialisation now happens during the splash screen and no longer between splash screen and appearance of the UI.

Comment: One thing to note here is that iOS automatically kills the process if the FinishedLaunching doesn't return in 7 seconds or less. So if you have any long running init processes, you have to run those on a background thread and allow the main UI thread to return from that method.